# Adding padding to packet using scapy

Tags: python, header, scapy, packet

how to inject zeros to the end of the UDP segment’s header to make it equal to 20 bytes.
Can anyone help me?

this my code :

```
    if UDP in packet:
    """get layers after udp"""
    layer_after = packet[UDP].payload.copy()

    """build a padding layer"""
    pad = Padding()
    pad.load = '\x00' * 12

    layer_before = packet.copy()
    layer_before[UDP].remove_payload()
    packet = layer_before / pad / layer_after
```

and this is a output for a udp packet  :

```
before : b'\xb8\xaco6\x1c\xa2\xe8\xe72<eP\x08\x00E\x00\x00.\x0bT@\x00\xec\x11\x18~MH\xa9\x82\x83\xca\xf0W+iC8\x00\x1a\x85+H\x00Y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

--------------------------------------------------------------

after : b'\xb8\xaco6\x1c\xa2\xe8\xe72<eP\x08\x00E\x00\x00.\x0bT@\x00\xec\x11\x18~MH\xa9\x82\x83\xca\xf0W+iC8\x00\x1a\x85+H\x00Y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

but it adds zeros to the end of packets!!!!!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do, sorry.  Do you want to create an UDP packet containing 20 bytes of data, all these bytes being set to 0, is that it? (so you'll have IP header + UDP header + 20 bytes of 0)

Comment: no, I want to inject zeros to the end of the UDP segment’s header to make it equal to 20 bytes

Comment: but UDP's header is constant.  so "inject zeros to the end of the UDP segment’s header" means adding a payload of 12 bytes.

Comment: but I want to add zeros right after the header, not end of payload

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question with yours.Maybe you can try this:

```
if UDP in packet:
    layer_after = packet[UDP].payload.copy()
    pad = Padding()
    pad.load = '\x00' * 12
    layer_before = packet.copy()
    layer_before[UDP].remove_payload()


    packet = layer_before / raw(pad) / layer_after
```

The padding will follow  the end of the UDP segment’s header.I hope this would help you.

Comment: If anybody needs, the same works for other packet types as well. Just replace 'UDP' with your packet type (e.g., TCP)